# Getting data from JQuery UI Popup back to the form

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, popup

I've got a form which, when certain conditions are met, will call a JQuery UI Popup.  What I need to do is, when the OK button is pressed, write what's in the popup's textbox to a hidden textbox on my form.  Is this possible?  It would seem like I just need to tweak my popup a little:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    //Total out of range dialog
    $(function () {
        $("#dialog2").dialog({
            modal: true,
            autoOpen: false,
            width: 570,
            buttons: {
                "Ok": function () {
                    //I would think I just need a little code here which
                    // writes the value inside the textbox to the hidden
                    // textbox on the form?
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                }
            }

        });
    });
</script>
```

Then my popup looks like this:

```
<div id="dialog2" title="ATTENTION">
    <table style="width:565px; border-spacing:0px; border-collapse:collapse;">
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 240px">
                <asp:Label ID="lblCommentBox" runat="server" Text="Comment:"></asp:Label>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtCommentBox" runat="server" CssClass="textbox" 
                             TextMode="multiline" Wrap="True" Height="70px" Width="420px" 
                             Font-Size="Small"></asp:TextBox>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a hidden field like this:

```
<input type="hidden" id="hfComment" />
```

Or an ASP.NET HiddenField like this:

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="hfComment" runat="server"></asp:HiddenField>
```

Then you're right, you can put the code in the place you thought you should:

```
$("#hfComment").val($("#txtCommentBox").val());
```

---

**PS**

Sometimes, ASP.NET changes the `ClientID` and  the generated HTML IDs don't match with the .aspx IDs you've created. If that's the case, then it's better to use some CSS classes for that purpose.

For example:

```
<!-- Inside your pop-up (etc) -->
<asp:TextBox ID="txtCommentBox" runat="server" CssClass="textbox txt-comment-box" 
                         TextMode="multiline" Wrap="True" Height="70px" Width="420px" 
                         Font-Size="Small"></asp:TextBox>

<!-- And then, your hidden field -->
<asp:HiddenField ID="hfComment" CssClass="hf-comment" runat="server"></asp:HiddenField>
```

Then your code would be like:

```
$(".hf-comment").val($(".txt-comment-box").val());
```